# write into a csv file in multiple cells

Tags: csv, perl

I am coding in perl, how can you write into a csv file multiple variables and put each one in a separate cell in the same line.
this a part of my Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant BUFSIZE => 6;
my $year += 1900;

my $input_file = 'path\ZONE0.txt';
my $outputfile = 'path\outputfile.csv';
open (my $BIN, "<:raw", $input_file) or die "can't open the file $input_file: $!";
my $buffer;
open(FH, '>>', $outputfile) or die $!;
while (1) {
    my $bytes_read = sysread $BIN, $buffer, BUFSIZE;
    die "Could not read file $input_file: $!" if !defined $bytes_read;
    last if $bytes_read <= 0;
    my @decimal= map { unpack "C", $_ } split //, $buffer;
    
    my $start= $decimal[0];
    
    my $DevType = $decimal[1];
    my @hexDevType = sprintf("0x%x", $DevType); 
    
    my @DevUID =($decimal[5], $decimal[4], $decimal[3], $decimal[2]);
    my @hexDevUID = map { sprintf("0x%x",$_) } @DevUID; 
    print FH $start, ' ' , print FH $DevType,' ',  @hexDevUID , "\n";
}

close $BIN;
```

this results in puting all the variable next to each other in one cell, which is not what  I want. can you help me separate the variables.

Comment: you can use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) Perl module to generate a CSV file instead of just printing them using file handler.

Comment: Also for the query - _this results in puting all the variable next to each other in one cell_, you can join `@hexDevUID` array contents with comma(`,`) and store it in scalar variable and print it in the csv file.

Comment: If you print a print statement, like you do at `print FH $start, ' ' , print FH $DevType ...`, it will add a `1` in the print, because a print statement that is successful returns 1. It will also print the messages in reverse order. E.g. `print "foo", print "bar"` will actually print `barfoo1`.

Comment: `print join(",", @decimal[0,1,5,4,3,2]), "\n";` can replace the last 6 lines of your `while` loop. (Ignoring the values in `@hexDevType` which you do not use in your code).

Answer (score 4):

CSV files don't have cells. I suspect you're opening the file in a spreadsheet program.

The secret of a CSV file is that the values are separated by commas. So you need to put commas between any values that you want to appear in separate cells in your spreadsheet.

It looks like your data is in `@hexDevUID`. The simplest way is to turn that into a comma-separated string using `join()`:

```
join(',', @hexDevUID)
```

But the more robust approach will be to use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).

Answer (score 1):

Bellow is modified OPs code which does not utilize any `CVS` modules for output.

Added error handling code for read error and insufficient number of read bytes for further processing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use constant BUFSIZE => 6;

my($buffer,$bytes_read);
my $infile  = shift || 'path\ZONE0.txt';
my $outfile = 'path\outputfile.csv';

open my $in, '<:raw', $infile
    or die "Can't open $infile: $!";

open my $out, '+>>', $outfile
    or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

do {
    $bytes_read = sysread $in, $buffer, BUFSIZE;
    
    die "Error: read from $infile: $!"  unless defined $bytes_read;
    error_handler($bytes_read)          unless $bytes_read == 6;

    my @decimal = map { ord } split //, $buffer;
    my($start,$DevType) = @decimal[0,1];
    my @hexDevUID = map { sprintf("0x%02x",$_) } @decimal[5,4,3,2];
    
    say $out join(',',($start,$DevType,@hexDevUID));
} while ( $bytes_read );

sub error_handler {
    my $bytes = shift;
    
    close $out;
    close $in;
    
    say "
        Error: called error_handler(\$read_bytes)
            Action: Emergency file closure to preserve data
            Cause:  Read insufficient $bytes bytes
    " unless $bytes == 0;

    exit $bytes ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The loop can be rewritten with use of [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) like following

```
do {
    $bytes_read = sysread $in, $buffer, BUFSIZE;
    
    die "Error: read from $infile: $!"  unless defined $bytes_read;
    error_handler($bytes_read)          unless $bytes_read == 6;

    my($start,$DevType,@devUID) = unpack('CCC4',$buffer);
    my @hexDevUID = reverse map { sprintf "0x%02x", $_ } @devUID;
    
    say $out join(',',($start,$DevType,@hexDevUID));
} while ( $bytes_read );
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will adding the errors handling to my code as it works just fine. However, this is not what I asked for, I do Need the csv files and I Need my data to be organiyed into cells. this is what i am struggling with at the moment .

Comment: @waffles123 -- Have you tried to open CSV file in MS Excel, Open Office/Libre Office? Once file is open you will see the data in the individual cells. I hope that you open the file as CSV file.